# implement undirect graph C++ using Adjacency List

Tags: c++, graph

I try to write Class Graph to create one graph - Indirect and constant-
with nodes that have value (double)
because I want use the value to search in the adjacent in every node So I  will send the node to this search function later !

but I have some problem with adjacent list , what is not correct ? 
I try to make every node to have there value and the nodes that adjacent to them!
here is my code :

```
class node{
public:
   double id;
   list<node> *adj;
    node(double id1) {
        id=id1;
    }

    node(){} //defult constructure
};

class Graph{
public:
node nodes[34];
Graph();
node findNode(double ct);
void addEdge(node a, node b);
};

   Graph::Graph(){
    int c=16;
    // creat nodes
    for (int i=0;i<=34;i++)
    {
        nodes[i].id=c;
        c++;
    }
    //creat Edges
    //adj to [0]
    addEdge(nodes[0],nodes[33]);
    addEdge(nodes[0],nodes[1]);
    addEdge(nodes[0],nodes[11]);
    addEdge(nodes[0],nodes[4]);
    //adj to [1]
    addEdge(nodes[1],nodes[10]);
    addEdge(nodes[1],nodes[24]);
    addEdge(nodes[1],nodes[11]);

    //adj to [2]
    addEdge(nodes[2],nodes[7]);
    addEdge(nodes[2],nodes[23]);
    addEdge(nodes[2],nodes[11]);
    //adj to [3]
    addEdge(nodes[3],nodes[26]);
    addEdge(nodes[3],nodes[14]);
    addEdge(nodes[3],nodes[23]);
    addEdge(nodes[3],nodes[31]);
    //adj to [4]
    addEdge(nodes[4],nodes[10]);
    addEdge(nodes[4],nodes[18]);
    addEdge(nodes[4],nodes[25]);
    addEdge(nodes[4],nodes[9]);
    addEdge(nodes[4],nodes[26]);
    //adj to [5]
    addEdge(nodes[5],nodes[25]);
    addEdge(nodes[5],nodes[8]);
    addEdge(nodes[5],nodes[27]);
    addEdge(nodes[5],nodes[32]);
    //adj to [6]
    addEdge(nodes[6],nodes[9]);
    addEdge(nodes[6],nodes[14]);
    addEdge(nodes[6],nodes[7]);
    addEdge(nodes[6],nodes[13]);
    //adj to [7]
    addEdge(nodes[7],nodes[18]);
    addEdge(nodes[7],nodes[26]);
    addEdge(nodes[7],nodes[16]);
    //adj to [8]
    addEdge(nodes[8],nodes[26]);
    addEdge(nodes[8],nodes[13]);
    addEdge(nodes[8],nodes[28]);
    addEdge(nodes[8],nodes[12]);
    //adj to [9]
    addEdge(nodes[9],nodes[24]);
    addEdge(nodes[9],nodes[26]);
    //adj to [10]
    addEdge(nodes[10],nodes[18]);
    //adj to [11]
    addEdge(nodes[11],nodes[18]);
    //adj to [12]
    addEdge(nodes[12],nodes[27]);
    addEdge(nodes[12],nodes[20]);
    addEdge(nodes[12],nodes[29]);
    //adj to [13]
    addEdge(nodes[13],nodes[20]);
    addEdge(nodes[13],nodes[14]);
    //adj to [14]
    addEdge(nodes[14],nodes[22]);
    addEdge(nodes[14],nodes[17]);
    //adj to [15]
    addEdge(nodes[15],nodes[31]);
    addEdge(nodes[15],nodes[21]);
    //adj to [16]
    addEdge(nodes[16],nodes[19]);
    //adj to [17]
    addEdge(nodes[17],nodes[20]);
    addEdge(nodes[17],nodes[30]);
    //adj to [18]
    //adj to [19]
    addEdge(nodes[19],nodes[20]);
    addEdge(nodes[19],nodes[21]);
    //adj to [20]
    addEdge(nodes[20],nodes[29]);
    //adj to [21]
    addEdge(nodes[21],nodes[30]);
    //adj to [22]
    addEdge(nodes[22],nodes[31]);
    addEdge(nodes[22],nodes[30]);
    //adj to [23]
    //adj to [24]
    addEdge(nodes[24],nodes[33]);
    //adj to [25]
    addEdge(nodes[25],nodes[33]);
    addEdge(nodes[25],nodes[32]);
    //adj to [26]
    // adj to[27]
    addEdge(nodes[27],nodes[28]);
    //adj to [28]
    addEdge(nodes[28],nodes[29]);
    //adj to [29]-[33]
    }

void Graph::addEdge(node a, node b){a.adj->push_front(b); // Add b to a’s list.

b.adj->push_front(a); // Add a to b’s list.
}

node Graph::findNode(double ct){
        int t=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=34;i++)
        {   
        if( nodes[i].id == ct)// find the node that have the current state 
            t=i;
        }
        return  nodes[t];
}}
```

Comment: `list<node> *adj;` -- Where is this pointer initialized?  And why is this a pointer and not simply `std::vector<std::list<node>> adj`?

Comment: class Graph::Graph{ - what is it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie really I want to use vector but I I don't know How to add the node in adj if it is vector of list :(?   thanx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors. For instance, here:

```
list<node> *adj;
```

I really think you meant this:

```
list<node*> adj;
```

Also, your first experimental graph should have 2 nodes, not 34.

More fundamentally, you when you write code you should start with something small and simple, then build up. If you write something big, it will be full of bugs that are difficult to diagnose.

Comment: I was think it is the same, thanks for your advice and help;

Answer (score 0):

Here is one glaring error:

```
 node nodes[34];
 //...
 for (int i=0;
       i<=34;  // <-- This should be i < 34
       i++)
 {
    nodes[i].id=c;
```

This is an out-of-bounds access to the `nodes` array.  On the last iteration, you will be accessing `nodes[34]`, which is a memory overwrite.

You make the same error here:

```
    for(int i=0;i<=34;i++)
    {   
        if( nodes[i].id == ct)//
```